# How send automatic reply on particular email id when an user registers?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have created a registration form in JSP with an input field for email address. When user submits the form, then the user must get an auto-reply on his/her email address. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not very clear.
Let me get the requirement right; you need the code to send an email to the user only on successful registration. correct?

In your servlet(which is invoked on submit action),

```
if(user input is valid){
  Step1: registerUser();
  Step2: send confirmationEmail();
} else {
  Step3: Exception case
}
```

Send email method would ideally send the request to an JMS(queue) to send the email to the desired user.
Below is a snippet to send an email.

```
//Sample java code to send email

public void sendEmail(){

        try{

            Properties props = null;

                if (props == null) {
                        props = System.getProperties();
                }

                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "<server host name>");

                Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("<from email id>"));            

                message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, "<Registered user email id>");          

                message.setSubject("<Subject of the email>");

                message.setContent("<Content of the email>", "text/plain");         

                Transport.send(message);    

                    logger.info("Sent Email :" + 
                        "From :" + message.getFrom() +
                        "To:" + message.getAllRecipients() +
                        "Subject:" + message.getSubject() );

            } catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
```

Answer (score 23):

Auto-reply? Sorry, that term makes no sense in this particular context. Auto-reply is more a setting on a mailserver which should automatically send a reply back on incoming emails, for example *"Thank you, your email is been received, your email will be answered within 24 hours."* or something. You don't need this here.

You just want to programmatically send a mail. The mail should contain a link which should activate the account so that the user will be able to login. You see this indeed often on other websites. Here's how you can go about this:

1. Setup/prepare a SMTP server. A SMTP server is a mail server. Like as that a HTTP server is a web server. You can use an existing one from your ISP or a public one like Gmail. You can even setup a completely own one. For example with [Apache James](http://james.apache.org/). Whatever way you choose, you should end up knowing the hostname, portnumber, username and password of the SMTP server.
2. Create a `Mailer` class which can take at least "from", "to", "subject" and "message" arguments and sends a mail using [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq-135477.html). Connect and login the SMTP server by hostname, portnumber, username and password. Create a mail session and send the mail based on the given arguments. Create a dummy test class with a `main()` method which runs and tests the `Mailer` class. Once you get it to work, proceed with next steps.
3. Create another database table `user_activation` with a PK `key` and FK `user_id` referring the PK `id` of an `user` table which you should already have. On the existing `user` table, add a boolean/bit field `active` which defaults to `false`/`0`.
4. When user registration and insert in the DB succeeds, get the insert `id` from the `user` table, generate a long and unique `key` with [`java.util.UUID`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) and insert them in `user_activation` table. Prepare a mail message with an activation link where the unique `key` is included as URL parameter or path and then send this message using the `Mailer` class you created.
5. Create a `Servlet` which is mapped on an URL pattern matching the activation key links, e.g. `/activate/*` and extracts the activation key from the URL. Select the associated user from the database and if any exist, then set its `active` field to `true`/`1` and remove the key from `user_activation` table.
6. On login, only select the user when `active=true` or `1`.

Comment: Hi BalusC .. This would be best algorithm for all those who wants this kind of functionality.

Comment: This is great(+1), i am going to do it this way in my application. I have just one doubt, should i erase the key value after the activation, so it cannot be reused or there is not need for that?

Comment: Definitely you need to delete it. See also point 5. Since you're using JSF, you could also just substitute "servlet" with a JSF view/backing bean.

Comment: If you don't want to delete the key (which is something I tried avoiding too), one can create an activation key with an expiry date timestamp. If a user activates after the expiry date, it won't be picked up. Once the activation is successful, another timestamp is populated which specify when the activation key was activated. This is a good approach as it can give you an indication on how many users registered but are not yet activated.

Comment: Is it essential/crucial to store the activation key in the database? Is it not enough to store into the user session? Is it just dependent upon the requirements?

Comment: @Tiny: what if the email got delayed, or if enduser clicks the link after the session expires, or if the mailclient opens a new/different browser window, or if the webpage is stateless, etc?

Comment: Is this actually the way to go? I mean.. doing all this by hand and programmatically? Aren't there any "ready to go" solutions? Maybe take a look at [my question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37459351/how-to-establish-an-automated-email-service-for-a-website).

Answer (score 0):

What about adding user's email address to Bcc field (Blind Carbon Copy)?

Comment: Nope i want only to give auto-reply to user as "Registration is got successful"..thats when user got registration completed/when clicked on submit button.How to achieve it??