# How to establish an automated email service for a website?

Tags: java, email, web

I seem to fail at googling this specific thing: Like almost every website I too want to provide an automated email service for stuff like "password reset" or "validate email" after user registration.

However, I have not really an idea how I would do that and/or where to start. There must be some fast, easy and cheap solutions out there since this is quite a common issue for websites and I do not intend to re-invent the wheel for this problem.

So: What do I have to do to get such an automated email service for my website that works with my domain of course and where can I get started?

I am aware that I can use e.g. [`JavaMail`](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2075785/java-se/javamail-quick-start.html) to send emails as I like but do I still have to do everything by hand here or can I use an existing service?

Comment: Upvoted your question. I never really thought about alternatives to using the java email api. At most places I have worked we put the content of the email on a middleware system and it gets handled off by a different application (custom built i think most of the time) hope to see some answers here

Comment: @steelshark Thank you! I am currently looking at [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com). It was rather simple to test it and it provides 12k/month free emails which should be enough for now ^^. I am using the Java API which you can get with Maven and I've seen also a Python API.

Answer (score 0):

On my site, I custom built it. You send the email out with the "guid" for password resets and validate emails and then you handle that on your website when they click the links. I think doing it yourself will be just as easy as trying to use a third party imo. Setting up a mail server isn't that hard, it might seem daunting at first, but theirs plenty of good ones available without charge. Configuring it to send mail properly, takes a little work (A lot of it is configured out of the box), but an excellent resource you can use is [Unlock The Inbox](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/default/). Just go through the free resources on the left about all the different things to be aware of. Then you can hook in 3rd party email marketing campaign managers without cost as well like phplist. It will give you more flexibility over time.